# Get Array of Dates Between 2 Dates

Tags: vba, excel

I need help creating an array of dates between 2 dates. I am trying to export holidays from MS Project calendar using the Exceptions object. However, each Calendar.Exception isn't a single date. They can be defined as a range of dates (eg Christmas holidays).

```
Sub ArrayOfDates()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, aDates() As Date
    StartDate = #1/1/2018#
    EndDate = #1/31/2018#

    'create array of dates inclusive of endpoints
    If EndDate > StartDate Then

    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I went with the approach that eliminated the array:

```
Sub ExportCalendarHolidays()
    Dim calThisPrjCalendar As Calendar, excPeriod As Exception, OutputFileName As String, sOutputLine As String
    Dim Period As Date

    Set calThisPrjCalendar = ActiveProject.Calendar

    OutputFileName = ActiveProject.Path & "\" & "Holidays_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss") & ".csv"
    Open OutputFileName For Output As #1

    For Each excPeriod In calThisPrjCalendar.Exceptions
        For Period = excPeriod.Start To excPeriod.Finish
            sOutputLine = Format(Period, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            Print #1, sOutputLine
        Next Period
    Next

    'Cleanup
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to include the start and end on the Array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all dates between 2 dates in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102506/get-all-dates-between-2-dates-in-vba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will create the Array including the start and end date. The lines marked as Debug can be deleted. The loop at the end is just to verify the dates.

Edit: Edited ending loop to look nicer.

```
Sub ArrayOfDates()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, aDates() As Date
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, totalDates As Integer
    StartDate = #1/1/2018#
    EndDate = #1/31/2018#
    DateLoop = StartDate
    totalDates = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
    ReDim aDates(totalDates)
    x = 0
    Do While DateLoop <= EndDate
        aDates(x) = DateLoop
        Cells(x + 1, 1).Value = DateLoop ' Debug Line
        DateLoop = DateAdd("d", 1, DateLoop)
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    For y = 0 To UBound(aDates)
        Cells(y + 1, 3).Value = aDates(y) ' Debug Line
        Cells(y + 1, 4).Value = "Array Spot: " & y 'Debug Line
    Next y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To just get all the dates, you could do something like.

```
Dim dtDate as Date, dtStartDate as date, dtEndDate as Date

dtStartDate = #1/1/2018#
dtEndDate = #1/31/2018#

For dtDate = dtStartDate To dtEndDate
    'code to do each date
Next dtDate
```