# The resulting data is not within the selected dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to extract data based on a date range but the filter does not correctly recognise the start/end date values. The results are erratic, or no result at all.

```
Sub CopyDataBasedOnDate()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet

StartDate = Worksheets("Macro").Range("j8").Value
  EndDate = Worksheets("Macro").Range("j9").Value

Set MainWorksheet = Worksheets("RawData")

MainWorksheet.Activate

Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Sort _
      key1:=Range("a4"), order1:=xlAscending, _
       Header:=x1Yes

Range("a4").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A5")
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Call SumCell
Range("a1").Select
MainWorksheet.Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitely use `Range() ... .Criteria: ...` , cezarypiatek answer in [Get all dates between 2 dates in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102506/get-all-dates-between-2-dates-in-vba)  is a solution if you want to use `Range() ... .Criteria: ...` a solution is in [Filtering between two dates in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820757/filtering-between-two-dates-in-excel-vba)

So basically convert `StartDate` and `EndDate` to double using `CDbl`

Answer (score 0):

Excel interprets Date like a Long variable. If your data format is  not the same with the (En) default data format, you may have matching problems. So use Clng(Your Date). Try please the next code. It is referring only to the filtering part:

```
Sub CopyDataBasedOnDate()
 Dim StartDate As Date
 Dim EndDate As Date
 Dim MainWorksheet As Worksheet

  StartDate = Worksheets("Macro").Range("j8").Value
  EndDate = Worksheets("Macro").Range("j9").Value

 Set MainWorksheet = Worksheets("RawData")

 MainWorksheet.Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Sort _
      key1:=MainWorksheet.Range("a4"), order1:=xlAscending, _
       Header:=xlYes

 MainWorksheet.Range("a4").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(EndDate), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```